# Registration Form HTML,PHP,MySQLI dont see error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to code a registration form for my personal webpage as a experiment.

It's possible to load the webpage, but anything happens.

There isn't anything inserted in the database.

Here is the HTML code for the form (see that I'm using require_once to charge the php code, because of that the action="" is empty :) ):
sign-up.php

```
<!-- Incluimos el php de registro -->
<?php 
require_once('php/register.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cristian Pinela | Página Personal</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="logo">Cristian Pinela</h1>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="log-in.php">Inicia Sesión</a></li>
        <li><a href="sign-up.php">Registrate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Formulario de registro</h2>
        <!-- Mostramos los posibles errores que haya durante el registro -->
        <?php echo $succes; ?>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
        <p>Por favor, rellena el formulario para crear tu cuenta</p>
        <form method="POST" action=""> 
            <label for="name">Nombre completo:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" >
            <br>

            <label for="email">email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required">
            <br>

            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required">
            <br>

            <label for="confirm_password">Confirmar contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" required="required">
            <br>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

        </form>


    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Todos los derechos reservados Cristian Pinela</p>

    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the main php code for the registration process:

Registration.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    if($query = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = ?")) {
        $error = '';

        /* Asignamos los parámetros con Bind parameters (s=string, i=int, b=blob, etc). En nuestro caso ponemos email con s, ya que es un string */
        $query ->bind_param('s',$email);
        $query ->execute();

        //Almacenamos el resultado, así checkeamos si existe en la base de datos 
        $query -> store_result();

        if ($query->num_rows > 0){
            $error .= '<p class="error">El correo ya se encuentra registrado </p>';
        } 
        else {
            //Validamos la contraseña
            if (strlen($password) < 6) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">La contraseña debe tener al menos 6 carácteres</p>';
            }
            if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Entra una contraseña de confirmación </p>';
            } else {
                if (empty($error) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Las contraseñas no coinciden </p>';
                }
            
            }

            if (empty($error)) {
                $insertQuery = $db ->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?);");
                $insertQuery = bind_param("sss",$fullname,$email,$password_hash);
                $result = $insertQuery -> execute();

                if ($result) {
                    $error .= '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error"> Algo fue mal! </p>';
                }
                
            }
            
        }

    }
    $query -> close();
    $insertQuery -> close();
    //Cerramos conexión DB
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

Here is the config.php to access to the DB
config.php

```
<?php
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost:3306'); //Servidor
define('DBUSERNAME', 'cristian.pinela'); //Usuario
define('DBPASSWORD', 'private'); //Contraseña
define('DBNAME', 'cristianpinela'); //Base de datos

/* Conectamos a la base MySQL: */
$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
// Check db connection
if ($db === false) {
    die("Error: connection error. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Here is the session.php to check the session
session.php

```
<?php

//Iniciamos la sesión de la
session_start();

//Si el usuario está actualmente logeado, lo redirect al welcome page

if (isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && $_SESSION["userid"] == true) {
header("location: index.html");
exit;
}

?>
```

I've benn expending days on this and I dont see any error.

I will really apreciate if somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your code you include `php/register.php` but on the question you put `Registration.php`, incorrect filename? In `register.php`, if you put a `var_dump()` at the top, does it appear when loading?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Have you tried to get the raw SQL query and run it in phpmyadmin? Does it work?

Comment: Hi @Ruben! Thanks a lot for your help. See that I'm loading the code in the begining of the html code. I tried to do what you told me but It doesn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` It is advisable you really should set your own custom `'cost'` value on this line, typically around 14 or more...Or better yet use `ARGON_2i` if you're able to.

Comment: `define('DBPASSWORD', 'private'); //Contraseña`  this is a **VERY BAD HABIT** Setting a *Defined* variable in PHP means it is available in all scopes and to all parts of PHP, which raises a huge compromise window and risk the DB connection details can be extracted or accessed in unintended ways. Look at what you're doing; you need the password **once** just a couple of lines later, so you can simply type it in directly or use a normal variable you than then immediately `unset`.

Comment: `trim($_POST['confirm_password'])` It is bad practise to trim passwords. What if my password is meant to be `' horses and spaces here 4ever!'` with a space before the first word..... you should not `trim` password fields.

Comment: `mysqli_close($db);` You should not be using this with your other *Object Orientated* connection details. You should be using `$db->close();` as a direct replacement. [See here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

Comment: `$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, ... );` You should also move away from using `mysqli_connect` instead building the connection as a clean object rather than a variable. For example the same code should be replaced with: `$db = new mysqli(DBSERVER, ....);` [see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect)

Comment: `require_once('php/register.php');` While this works, the syntax is not correct. You should remove the brackets. They're unnessecary for `require` statements. Also if you are manually loading simple PHP pages you probably don't need to check if it's loading just `_once` (this is resource wasteful). Correct: `require_once 'php/register.php';` Or even better `require 'php/register.php';`

Answer (score 0):

The deal here is you are not loading the script on your form, when the `action=""` it work as self page.

just change the action to this:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/Registration.php">
   //form
 </form>
```

Comment: This is not correct as his registration code is to be inserted at the top of sign-up.php.

Comment: You can make a exclusive php script file just for your registration if you want, so currently he have on `Registration.php` or `register.php` i dont know how is he handling this, also your comment is available to, just adding the script to the sign-up.php if he want. Regards!

Comment: I assumed it was inserted at the top considering he is populating the `$error` variable to display above the form.

Comment: @mulquin probably he dont know what is doing xd

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

```
                $insertQuery = bind_param("sss",$fullname,$email,$password_hash);
```

I have to write:

```
            $insertQuery -> bind_param("sss",$fullname,$email,$password_hash);
```